# wordpress wpautop function adds empry paragraph tags

Tags: wordpress

I created an "About Me" widget which contains title, image and description fields. 
I want to replace new lines with html tags `<p>text</p>`.
When I try to use "wpautop" function it adds empty tags "`<p></p>`" in the beginning and end of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Please use javascript for this-

```
$('p:empty').remove();
```